# Populate NSTableView with a new object by clicking a button

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

Im trying to populate an NSTableView with a custom object by clicking a button. My custom class has just NSString properties: `title` and `volume`. I customized the init method to create an object and add it to my array that is hooked up to my table view. Then on the method for my button I had it create another object and add it to the array. When I run the program the object from the init method does display correctly. However, when I click my button I get nothing.

Here is the code for my header file:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource>{
    NSMutableArray *_myArray;}

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender;

@end
```

and here is my implementation:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "trade.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate


-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        _myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        trade *firstTrade = [[trade alloc]init];
        [firstTrade setTitle:@"Trade One"];
        [firstTrade setVolume:@"Volume 01"];
        [_myArray addObject:firstTrade];}
    return self;}

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    trade *secondTrade = [[trade alloc]init];
    [secondTrade setTitle:@"Trade two"];
    [secondTrade setVolume:@"Volume 02"];
    [_myArray addObject:secondTrade];
    [_tableView reloadData];}

-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView{
    return _myArray.count;}

-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{
    if ([tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"Title"]){
        trade *item = [_myArray objectAtIndex:row];
        return item.title;
    }else{
        trade *item = [_myArray objectAtIndex:row];
        return item.volume;}}

@end
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here as what I did in the init method is pretty much the same thing I did in button method. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is a picture of the program after I run it:

[tableView program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZKcE.png)

As you can see my first object appears in the table view, but not the second.

While looking at this project I duplicated the `[_tableView reloadData];` line and placed a breakpoint on the second one so I could see what was going on right after the first one is called. One thing I noticed is that `_myArray` does now contain 2 objects after the button click.

However, when I look into `_tableView` it shows that `_myArray` only contains 1 object. How is it that the object is actually getting added but the table view is only getting 1?

Here is a picture for reference:[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoY6E.png)

Comment: Try debugging your code, i'm guessing your table view outlet is not set properly.

Comment: I edited the original question with a couple things I found while looking at the code and setting some breakpoints.

Comment: Krzysztof is right. _tableView of _dataSource(AppDelegate) is nil in the Debug picture.